# Confuse about Module and Component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

All:

I am pretty new to Angular2, there is one concept confuse about `@NgModule` and `@Component`:

Are they totally different conceptually or they are similar and the main diff is `@NgModule` is more like container component while `@Component` is more like functional component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are entirely different. A module is to wrap zero or more components, directives, pipes, and services up to be imported and reused at once.

Modules were introduced for lazy loading in combination with the router and ahead of time compilation (AoT).